# (Java) storing every string that starts and ends with a specific word into an array

Tags: java, html, arrays, sorting, data-analysis

Currently im trying to make a app for myself, that translates my school's web timetable for my class into a table in an android app.
Im having trouble at finding certain Strings in HTML Code (String) that starts with `<tr>` and ends with `</tr>`

Im using this right now:

```
public void sortData(String str) {
    String subStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("<tr>"), str.indexOf("</tr>"));
    String[] output = subStr.split(",");
    for (String all:output) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

but it only gives me one of the lines:

```
<TR><TD rowspan="2" width="5"></TD><TD><b>HEID TECH</b></TD><TD rowspan="2" width="5"></TD><TD>2017 / 2018</TD><TD rowspan="2" width="5"></TD><TD align="right"> <b>Untis 2018</b></TD><TD rowspan="2" width="5"></TD>
```

iam using this HTML code as the main string:
https://intern.heid-tech.de/alle/stupla/Klassen/Kla1_ohne_1BK2T1.htm

Comment: Show what you expect to find and what you find actually.

Comment: im trying to get this as a output: <tr>
<td align="center"><table><tbody><tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
<td colspan="12" nowrap="1" align="center"><table><tbody><tr><td nowrap="1" align="center"><font size="5" face="Arial" color="#000000">
Montag
</font></td></tr>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a requirements specification, not a question.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: i can't express myself that clearly because english isn't my primary language, im just trying to get help, but thanks for nothing..

Comment: You could use JSOUP: https://jsoup.org/download

Answer (score 0):

You are taking everything between the first `<tr> </tr>` and throwing away rest of the string.

you should probably call this method again with the remainder of the string as parameter. For example

```
 int endIndex = str.indexOf("</tr>");
 String subStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("<tr>"), endIndex);
```

and after the for loop call the method again

```
sortData(str.substring(endIndex));
```

Of course, don't forget to add an end condition

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Split
{
    Split()
    {
    }

    void SplitString(String str)
    {
        System.out.println(str.substring(str.indexOf(">")+1,str.lastIndexOf("<")));
    }

    public static void Main(String args[])
    {
        split obj1=new split();
        obj1.splitString("<tr> hello world</tr>");
    }
}
```

Comment: try this code for get the string in between the <tr> and </tr> tags

Comment: Hey, there! Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be best if you explained what your code is doing and why it helps solve the issue at hand. Cheers!

Comment: ya sure next time i will take care about your point. (code + explanation)   @MatheusAvellar thank you :)